# How to convert vb .net function to c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to convert a vb .net function to c#..i have converted it but it is not returning the output as expected

VB .net Function

```
 Public Function DecryptString(ByVal EncryptedString As String) As String

    Dim TempLine As String = Nothing
    Dim TempChar As String = Nothing
    Dim FinalStr As String = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim value As Integer = 0

    FinalStr = Nothing
    value = 0

    If EncryptedString <> "" Then
        For i = 1 To Len(EncryptedString)
            Try
                TempChar = Mid(EncryptedString, i, 1)
                value = Asc(TempChar)
                value = (value - (120))
                FinalStr = FinalStr & Chr(value)
            Catch
                DecryptString = ""
                Exit Function
            End Try
        Next
        DecryptString = FinalStr
        Exit Function
    End If

    DecryptString = ""
End Function
```

C# function

```
 public string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
    {
        string substr = null;
        char TempChar; int ExtraChars = 0; string ExtraOnes = "";
        string FinalStr = null;
        int i = 0;
        int value = 0;
        FinalStr = null;
        value = 0;
        if ((EncryptedString != ""))
        {
            for (i = 1; (i <= EncryptedString.Length); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    substr = EncryptedString.Substring((i - 1), 1);
                    TempChar = Convert.ToChar(substr);
                    value = (value - 120);
                    FinalStr = (FinalStr + ((char)(value)));
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {

                    // TODO: Exit Function: Warning!!! Need to return the value
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return FinalStr;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I am not able to find why it is not returing the right output

Comment: It looks like you're missing a step after `TempChar = Convert.ToChar(substr);` - you need to assign the ASCII value of the character.  Try this:  `value = (int)TempChar;`.

Comment: thnx for helping me out friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**[VB.Net to C# Conversion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=b5aad756-1a62-4476-b4f4-264e98b31492)**

```
public string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
{
    string functionReturnValue = null;

    string TempLine = null;
    string TempChar = null;
    string FinalStr = null;
    int i = 0;
    int value = 0;

    FinalStr = null;
    value = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EncryptedString)) {
        for (i = 1; i <= Strings.Len(EncryptedString); i++) {
            try {
                TempChar = Strings.Mid(EncryptedString, i, 1);
                value = Strings.Asc(TempChar);
                value = (value - (120));
                FinalStr = FinalStr + Strings.Chr(value);
            } catch {
                functionReturnValue = "";
                return functionReturnValue;
            }
        }
        functionReturnValue = FinalStr;
        return functionReturnValue;
    }

    functionReturnValue = "";
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

**Refer:**

1.) **[Strings.Asc Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78sb8546.aspx)** :Returns an Integer value representing the character code corresponding to a character.
(Namespace:  Microsoft.VisualBasic)

2.) **[What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721201/whats-the-equivalent-of-vbs-asc-and-chr-functions-in-c)**:

For Asc() you can cast the char to an int like this:

```
int i = (int)your_char;
```

and for Chr() you can cast back to a char from an int like this:

```
char c = (char)your_int;
```

Comment: OP will need to add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly to use that method. [Strings.Asc Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78sb8546.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty to clean up the code a little as it's easier to locate errors this way:

```
Public Function DecryptString(ByVal EncryptedString As String) As String

    Dim FinalStr As New StringBuilder
    Dim value As Integer = 0

    If not String.IsNullOrEmpty(EncryptedString) Then
        For Each c as Char in EncryptedString
            Try
                value = Asc(c)
                value -= 120
                FinalStr.Append(Chr(value))
            Catch
                Return ""
            End Try
        Next
    End If

    Return Finalstr.ToString

End Function
```

And as C# version:

```
public string DecryptString(string EncryptedString) {

    StringBuilder FinalStr = new StringBuilder();
    int value = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EncryptedString)) {

        foreach (char c in EncryptedString) {
            try {
                value = (int)c;
                value -= 120;
                FinalStr.Append(((char)(value)));
            }
            catch (System.Exception e) {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
    return Finalstr.ToString;
}
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: your code is also not working. The resulted string is showing ]̤ɤ character in place of = sign. Thnx anyway

Comment: I don't know what you are decoding, I'm just using your formula to do it :-)

Comment: @shalini, but that being said, it looks like your input-string is UNICODE and not straight ASCII. If you could show an example how the string gets encoded, in what format as well as an example of a raw string and encoded string, we might be able to help you a step further.

Comment: Hi Abdias! While encrypting 120 is added and while decrypting 120 is subtracted. The code is same

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you lose (never use) `TempChar`.

If you just make this change, you're home:

```
value = (TempChar - 120);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work - you need to cast `TempChar` to an int.

Comment: Works for me. I thought I'd had to cast, but didn't.

Comment: I'll be darned.  There must be an implicit cast going on behind the scenes.

Comment: +1 for the shortest code solution :)  Though it never hurts to be explicit in your code for the devs coming behind you.

Answer (score 0):

You're never assigning the value of the character to `value`, so you're going to wind up with -120, -240, etc.

Here's another way to do it, without all the string manipulation:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EncryptedString))
{
    for (i = 0; i < EncryptedString.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            TempChar = EncryptedString[i];
            value = (int)TempChar - 120;
            FinalStr = FinalStr + (char)(value);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: Exit Function: Warning!!! Need to return the value
            return "";
        }
    }
```