# Converting two lines from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I can't seem to properly convert the following from VB.NET to C#--

```
iKeyChar = Asc(mid(g_Key, i, 1))
iStringChar = Asc(mid(strCryptThis,i,1))
```

Here's my converted C# code, which doesn't seem to output equivalent values--

```
iKeyChar = Convert.ToInt32(g_Key.Substring(i, 1));
iStringChar = Convert.ToInt32(strCryptThis.Substring(i, 1));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

That's because `Mid` is one based while `Substring` is zero based. Try it this way:

```
iKeyChar = (int)Convert.ToChar(g_Key.Substring(i-1, 1));
iStringChar = (int)Convert.ToChar(strCryptThis.Substring(i-1, 1));
```

Comment: Also Asc [returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.71).aspx) an ANSI code but Convert.ToInt32 tries to convert the string to a number, e.g. "1" is 1, "2' is 2 etc.

Comment: That kind of depends on if and what they have their Option Base set to doesn't it?

Comment: @MarkJ - Yeah I've heard of that. Do you know of an exact analog to Asc in C# (other than importing Microsoft.VisualBasic)?

Comment: @DanielGraham - "Option Base"? I thought VB.NET didn't have that?

Comment: @MarkJ - Apparently casting it to `char` *then* casting it to `int` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's the ASCII bit that's the problem. See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/13fec271-9a97-4b71-ab28-4911ff3ecca0 and here: [What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721201/whats-the-equivalent-of-vbs-asc-and-chr-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        int iKeyChar = Convert.ToChar(g_key.Substring(i, 1));
        int iStringChar = Convert.ToChar(strCryptThis.Substring(i, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply access the desired char by its index withing the string and cast it to `int`:

```
iKeyChar = (int)g_Key[i - 1];
iStringChar = (int)strCryptThis[i - 1];
```

Note that index of the string characters is zero based (as System Down said in his post).