# Translating VB6 chars to C# strings

Tags: c#, vb6

I want to upgrade an old VB6 project to newer technologies and I have these values below and don't know how to translate them.

```
Chr(&H31) & Chr(&H1) & Chr(&H50) & Chr(&H31) & Chr(&H17)
```

So my first question is how do I identify these? Is it hexadecimal values or something else? I don't seem to find them in a ascii table. What does the 'H' stand for?

Secondly, how do I make a c# string out of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721201/whats-the-equivalent-of-vbs-asc-and-chr-functions-in-c)

Comment: I've tried to convert them with Convert.ToChar() but it doesn't recognize the values

Comment: Look at the answer posted by DavidG. Also, yes `&H31` is a hexadecimal value. So in C# you'd write: `0x31`

Comment: Ty MrPaulch, please write an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Chr` converts a character code into the character, in C# you can just cast:

```
char c1 = (char)0x31;
```

(Also changing to use C#'s hexidecimal literals rather than VB6's.)

But when building a string, using escapes is easier:

```
string s1 = "\x31\x01\x50\x31\x16";
```

Comment: Note that "special" characters like `\x01` (anything below `\x20`) indicate binary data are not necessarily safe in a string. Depending on the use, a byte array may be better.

Answer (score 1):

As your "characters" include special/control/unprintable characters (`1<SOH>P1<ETB>`), I expect this is actually non string data, and as such should not be stored as a string.

Depending on the actual desired usage, you will be better off with a byte array:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x31, 0x01, 0x50, 0x31, 0x17 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to identify the function parameter and still wnat the same result, you can always call the native VB function from your C# application.

- You just need to add the reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`
- Call the function `Strings.Chr`

You are more confident of the result :)