# C# Equivalent to VB6 Chr(number)

Tags: c#, vb6, chr

I have this code:

```
Dim sCenter As String
sCenter = Chr(27) + Chr(97) + Chr(1)
```

And I'm trying to convert to a C# code. Online converters always fail to convert... :(

So, what is the C# equivalente of `Chr(number)`?

*Maybe `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(10);`*

Comment: similar question asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721201/whats-the-equivalent-of-vbs-asc-and-chr-functions-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648781/how-to-get-character-for-a-given-ascii-value

Comment: Actually, one of the deleted answers was very close:
Soner Gonul wrote

    string sCenter;
    sCenter = (char)27 + (char)97 + (char)1;

Which doesn't work because a `char`  is still basically an integer, so that just yields 125.

However, if you add a `char` to a `string`, C# works properly , hence: `sCenter = "" + (char)27 + (char)97 + (char)1;`

Comment: @JamesCurran Yeah, I realized that after I post and that's why I deleted. I undeleted my answer based your suggestion if you don't mind :)

Comment: See a complete answer: [C# Char from Int used as String - the real equivalent of VB Chr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976240/c-sharp-char-from-int-used-as-string-the-real-equivalent-of-vb-chr)

Comment: [What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/721201/608639).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Feel like taking risk to answer but how about?

```
string sCenter;
sCenter = "" + (char)27 + (char)97 + (char)1;
```

Thanks to James Curran's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980022/c-sharp-equivalent-to-vb6-chrnumber/26980089#comment42495273_26980022) about `char` integral addition. As his suggested, I added meaningless `""` with `char` to get `string + char` which uses `.ToString()` with `String.Concat` method at background.

Comment: I know it's old, but...  with the new Interpolated Strings in C#, you can do this:
$"{(char)26}"