# Encryption difference after converting VB to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, encryption, ascii

Was trying to convert a code from VB to C#, see VB code below

```
Dim StrCount As Int16
Dim str1, str2, EncryptedStr As String
EncryptedStr = String.Empty
theString = "Test@1234"

For StrCount = 1 To Len(theString)
    str1 = Asc(Mid(theString, StrCount, 1)) - 1
    str2 = str1 + Asc(Mid(StrCount, 1))
    EncryptedStr = EncryptedStr + Chr(str2)
Next
```

Converted C# code

```
string EncryptedStr = string.Empty;
Encoding encode1 = Encoding.ASCII;
Byte[] encodedBytes = encode1.GetBytes("Test@1234");  

for (int count = 0; count < encodedBytes.Length; count++)
{
    int str1 = encodedBytes[count] - 1;
    Encoding encode2 = Encoding.ASCII;
    Byte[] encodedBytes1 = encode2.GetBytes((count + 1).ToString());  
    int str2 = str1 + (int)encodedBytes1[0];
    EncryptedStr += Convert.ToChar(str2);
}
```

Its working fine, but the problem i am facing is the encrypted password is different in VB & C#

I tried encrypting a string "Test@1234", the encrypted result was

VB: „–¥§tfhjl

C#: ¥§tfhjl

I debug and noticed that in C# Convert.ToChar(132) & Convert.ToChar(150) is giving empty value.

Can anybody explain, what is going wrong here

Comment: does if only differ with strings of uneven char Count?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander: No it does not only differ for even or uneven strings.

Comment: I checked both Code examples with LinqPad and they both return the same string...

Comment: Personally, I do think that the word "[encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)" is somewhat misleading here.

Comment: pretty depending on your locales/regional Settings: may be you test it by c# snippet `string test="Test:";

for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
 test += Convert.ToChar(i);
}

Console.WriteLine(test);`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution and the one that will be identical to your original code is to use the `Asc` and `Chr` methods in the `VisualBasic` namespace as these have identical functionality.

But

Asc uses ANSI which can change on different locales and different machine, so if you really want to be stubborn, you can try and emulate this by explicitly defining the encoding to use.

This produces the same result on *my* machine  (but as be careful to test it on other machines):

```
Public Function EncryptString(aString As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")
    For i = 0 To aString.Length - 1
        Dim x = enc.GetBytes(aString.Substring(i, 1))(0) - 1
        Dim y = enc.GetBytes((i + 1).ToString)(0) + x
        Dim b() As Byte = {y}
        sb.Append(enc.GetString(b))
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

So the (untested) C# equivalent is:

```
public string EncryptString(string aString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
    for (var i = 0; i < aString.Length; i++)
    {
        var x = enc.GetBytes(aString.Substring(i, 1))[0] - 1;
        var y = enc.GetBytes((i + 1).ToString())[0] + x;
        byte[] b = {y};
        sb.Append(enc.GetString(b));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: I have made a change to specify the encoding explicitly, so this should match `Asc` more closely

Comment: 1) Thanks 
2) Cannot implicitly convert int to byte so modified line
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(y);
3) Result i am getting is double quote "

I did exactly as you said...

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment for this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/721207/1641172), VB.NET returns ANSI codes in the current windows code page, not ASCII codes. Don't expect to get the same output unless you use the same function, reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use `Strings.Asc` and `Strings.Chr` to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net legacy Asc function, really is using System.Text.Encoding.Default. In your C# version, you are using ASCII. Check that:

```
        string EncryptedStr = string.Empty;
        Encoding encode1 = Encoding.Default; //.ASCII;
        Byte[] encodedBytes = encode1.GetBytes("Test@1234");

        for (int count = 0; count < encodedBytes.Length; count++)
        {
            int str1 = encodedBytes[count] - 1;
            Encoding encode2 = Encoding.Default;
            Byte[] encodedBytes1 = encode2.GetBytes((count + 1).ToString());
            int str2 = str1 + (int)encodedBytes1[0];
            EncryptedStr += Convert.ToChar(str2);
        }
```

Comment: Not strictly True. Asc uses System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding, but In mono, on Ubuntu 12.04, System.Text.Encoding.Default is System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, while on Windows 7, it seems to be System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding.

Comment: @MattWilko  Ok, but I'm not saying that, I say that he is using Default encoding (whichever) in Vb.net, and forcing to ASCII on C#.

Comment: @NKhan -1 with no more info about "it's not working" it's not a good incentive to improve an answer

Comment: But `Encoding.Default` is not necessarily the same as Asc (which uses ANSI) because the Default can change on different locales and machines

Comment: @MattWilko aaah I understand you now. Agree then, thanks for explanation