# Convert full-width digits `０` through `９` to corresponding normal `0` through `9` in C#

Tags: c#

```
if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
{                        
    if (IsCharFullWidthDigits(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.KeyChar = Strings.Chr(Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) + 23680);
    }
}
```

If user inputs a full-width digit such as `０` to `９`, how to auto convert to the corresponding normal `0` or `9`? In VB.NET I used `Strings.Chr` and `Strings.Asc`, but I don't see the equivalent in C#. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of VB's Asc() and Chr() functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721201/whats-the-equivalent-of-vbs-asc-and-chr-functions-in-c)

Comment: I checked the page. But some codes inside only got few votes and there's no guarantee to say the codes are correct. I am going to test them.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the codes. thanks Keith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int diff = (int)'０' - (int)'0';
if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && IsCharFullWidthDigits(e.KeyChar))
{
        e.KeyChar = (char)(((int)e.KeyChar) - diff);
}
```

Comment: It answered my question on the codes. For my case, we can directly use int/char to cast.